# Drawing heat maps on Google Maps for iOS

Tags: objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google Maps SDK on iOS.

How can i draw heat maps on the Goolge Map ?

Drawing heat map using Javascript library is already available.

I want to know is it possible to do it using objective C ?